# Is there a portable conversion of a datetime column to string using SQL

Tags: sql, h2, sybase

I have a column defined as a datetime in sybase and have converted it to a string using

```
ISNULL(CAST(CAST(most_recent_trades.asof_date AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(20))
```

It turns out that the representation of this as a string in sybase differs from my unit test db which is H2.

```
In sybase
Sep  1 2016

In H2
2016-09-01
```

The column is defined as datetime in H2 as well.

Is there a way to convert the datetime column to a string that is the same string representation in both Sybase and H2 (I don't need the time portion of this if that helps any)?

EDIT :
I don't think there is any way to do this in a portable way with one function, so what I decided to do was use the YEAR, MONTH and DAY functions (they are all available in Sybase and H2), extract the parts and concatenate them to make a date that will look the same when represented as a string in both Sybase and H2. This works for me at this point.

Comment: You can use `convert()` in Sybase to choose the format you want.  I think that solves your problem.

Comment: there are two problems with convert : 1. the order of params differs between H2 and Sybase, 2. The result is the same as CAST

Comment: Usually you would use the ISO Format. In this case that is `2016-09-01` (the one that uses H2).

Answer (score 0):

I would use format `121` of the [CONVERT()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm) function and then get the date portion of it, as in:

```
substring(convert(varchar(30), most_recent_trades.asof_date, 121), 1, 10)
```

Comment: This doesn't even work in H2. I wouldn't be asking this question if I did not have a different unit test database from my production database!

Comment: This code works in Sybase to produce a date in ISO format. H2 is already giving you the ISO format by default.

Comment: This is production code. I cannot do things differently in production code depending on whether I am running unit tests or running in production.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a different RDBMS for unit testing vs production? You're creating work for no gain. Consider using the SAP ASE developer edition maybe instead - https://www.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-asewindm/index.html